# Restrict search function to favorites

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

Is there a way to restrict a full-text search to my favorites in [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, but there is a feature request on meta.SO: [Search in list of favorited questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3683). Apparently the search supported the parameter `infavorites:1` once, but this functionality was dropped when introducing the new search as this seems to be hard to implement in the current approach.

Answer (score 9):

Searching within *a* set of favourites has been re-implemented under the new [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) engine (around January 2013) across the entire network. The following search options are available:

- `infavorites:mine` - search within your own list of favourites;
- `infavorites:<userid>` - search within numerical `<userid>`'s favourites (yes, you can search through other user's list of favourites);

Since only *questions* can be added to your list of favourites, some search combinations would be contradictory. For example, [`infavorites:mine is:answer <stuff>`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+is%3Aanswer) for any `<stuff>` would always return 0 hits.

Related post on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com): [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/168244)